# Why are these two weights the same?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, weight

Let's assume we have a floating iceberg. A book says the following:

$$mg = V_{\mathrm{tot}}\rho_{\mathrm{ice}}g = V_{\mathrm{und}}\rho_{\mathrm{w}}g$$

where $V_{\mathrm{tot}}$ is the total volume, $P_\mathrm{ice}$ is the density of ice, $V_\mathrm{und}$ is the volume under water, and $P_\mathrm{W}$ is the density of the water.

I don't understand why that holds, can someone explain this to me, please?

Comment: Hi, we will need some clarifications on the various bodies involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iceberg feels two forces, weight and buoyancy.  Weight is depends on mass, and therefore density, of the ice.  This is the $V_{tot}$ term.  Buoyancy depends on the mass of the displaced water.  This in turn depends only on the volume of ice under water and the density of this water that was "pushed" out of the way by the ice.  This is the $V_{und}$ term.  Assuming acceleration of the ice is essentially zero, the weight of the ice must equal the weight of the displaced water.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of it like this:
The ice is in equilibrium, so the net force on it is zero. If you replace the ice with water that has volume $V_{und}$, the water would be in equilibrium too! So the weight of water with $V_{und}$ should be the same as the weight of ice with $V_{tot}$ resulting in: $V_{tot} ρ_{ice} g = V_{und} ρ_w g$